# Confusing usage of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: confidence-interval, estimators, central-limit-theorem

The CLT defined in Introduction to Mathematical Statistics (Hogg) 8th ed., states that given the samples $\mathbf X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma) $ with the mean and variance estimator $\bar X,S^2$, the following holds:

$$
\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S/\sqrt n}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)
$$as $n\to \infty$.

Now, an example in the book states that $$
\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(\bar X)}}\sim\mathcal N(0,1)
$$ (an approximation)
and stated that this equation is because of the CLT.

Clearly they are different in the denominator. $
S/n
$ is the **sample std of $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ divided by $\sqrt n$**  while $\sqrt{\text{Var}(\bar X)}$ is the **std of the estimator$\bar X$**

Can someone help me with their discrepancy? Or if the CLT is invoked differently for both of them

Comment: (Under random sampling), $V(\bar X)=\sigma^2/n$ and by Slutzky's Theorem, $S\to_p\sigma$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck aside from $\bar X$ does the formulation $\frac{T-t}{\sqrt{V(T)}}$ approach the unit Normal under the CLT for any **estimator** $T$?

Comment: Not any, but quite broadly, yes.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: @ChristophHanck Looking back, I think $
\frac{T-t}{\sqrt{V(t)}}\to_D N(0,1/n)
$ instead of the unit variance. The example on the book might have been my misunderstanding and it is not referring to $\bar X$ but the estimator $\bar X−\bar Y$
 to which the CLT does not anymore apply. Instead, the asymptotic Normal distribution of $\bar X - \bar Y$ is subtracted by its asymptotic $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which causes it to become **unit Normal**